# Best place to buy bags with exactly the maximum limits ryanair has in Rome, Italy?

Tags: luggage, italy, rome

I'm going to Rome on sunday and from there to greece by ryanair. My bag is too big so I'm planning to buy two for traveling having these limits

"You can carry one cabin bag weighing up to 10 kg with maximum dimensions of 55cm x 40cm x 20cm, plus 1 small bag up to 35 x 20 x 20 onboard the aircraft."

Anyone has any recommendations for the best places in Rome to buy two bags having **exatcly** these dimensions?

Comment: All the major brands (samsonite, delsey, etc.) have these...

Comment: A note here: your bag doesn't have to have exactly those dimensions (nobody is going to measure it with a ruler) - your bag must *fit into the box* having those dimensions.

Comment: Any decent _valigieria_ would quite probably have it, with comparable prices. Some might be closed on Sundays though.